# javascript alert is not working for some particular text

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="term_1.html" onClick="alert('A caldera is a circular shaped
landform depression caused by the eruption of a large, near surface
body of magma.'); return false">caldera</a>
```

I try to run this block but it is not working. When I write some other message in the `alert` ( except this ) it works fine. Would anyone tell me the exact problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string wraps to a new line, causing the `onclick` handler to break. Try this:

```
<a href="term_1.html" onclick="alert('A caldera is a circular shaped landform depression caused by the eruption of a large, near surface body of magma.'); return false">caldera</a>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9gbV/1/**

Comment: I'd go with Blender's answer.  A single line is preferable to the '\' that I demonstrated in mine, which is mostly there FYI.

Comment: @rrr: I never knew about that one working in HTML. You got my +1.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have a javascript string spanning multiple lines.  Keep the entire text of the alert on a single line (it will run off your screen) and it should work.

Alternatively you can add a \ at the end of each line of your string, e.g.:

```
<a href="term_1.html" onClick="alert('A caldera is a circular shaped\
landform depression caused by the eruption of a large, near surface\
body of magma.'); return false">caldera</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the new line in your text. Simply make the text in one line will work.